# Adding a vector to each row in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe and a function that returns a vector, I want to "add" those vectors to my frame like followed:

```
for i in range(len(Training_Frame)):
    Training_Frame.insert(i,'ONEcoded',onehot_processing(int(float(Training_Frame.iloc[i,-1])),numberOFclasses))
```

as an example, say the o`onehot_processing` function returns `[0,0,0,1,0]` each time. the `Training_Frame` first rows looks like:

```
row0 [1,2,3,4,5]
row1 [2,3,4,5,3]
.............
```

how can I add the returned vector as followed:

```
row0 [1,2,3,4,5,0,0,0,1,0]
row1 [2,3,4,5,3,0,0,0,1,0]
.............
```

The error message I get when I try to run the loop is :

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-1a385098ae56> in <module>()
      1 for i in range(len(Training_Frame)):
----> 2     Training_Frame.insert(i,'ONEcoded',onehot_processing(int(float(Training_Frame.iloc[i,-1])),numberOFclasses))

c:\users\engine\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in insert(self, loc, column, value, allow_duplicates)
   2507         """
   2508         self._ensure_valid_index(value)
-> 2509         value = self._sanitize_column(column, value, broadcast=False)
   2510         self._data.insert(loc, column, value,
   2511                           allow_duplicates=allow_duplicates)

c:\users\engine\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in _sanitize_column(self, key, value, broadcast)
   2654 
   2655             # turn me into an ndarray
-> 2656             value = _sanitize_index(value, self.index, copy=False)
   2657             if not isinstance(value, (np.ndarray, Index)):
   2658                 if isinstance(value, list) and len(value) > 0:

c:\users\engine\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in _sanitize_index(data, index, copy)
   2798 
   2799     if len(data) != len(index):
-> 2800         raise ValueError('Length of values does not match length of ' 'index')
   2801 
   2802     if isinstance(data, PeriodIndex):

ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index
```

**Update**

```
#Function to generate a onehot coded vector based on
#number of class & the given class ID
def onehot_processing(classID, numberOFclasses):
    one_hot_vector=np.zeros(numberOFclasses)
    one_hot_vector[classID-1] = 1
    return one_hot_vector
```

ClassID is saved in the last column of the dataframe

Comment: `numberOFclasses` is constant?

Comment: yes it's a constant that I set at the beginning

Comment: Hmmm, so `classID` is column with lists?

Comment: ClassIDs are values saved in last column,that change in each row, so I need to read each row of this column and give it to onehot function to get a different vector each time , the returned vector has the same size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me works add vector to `list` column:

```
a = [0,0,0,1,0]

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[[1,2,3,4,5],[2,3,4,5,3]]}, index=['row0','row1'])
print (df)
                    a
row0  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
row1  [2, 3, 4, 5, 3]

df['a'] = df['a'] + a
print (df)
                                   a
row0  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
row1  [2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
```

So use [`Series.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html) with custom function:

```
def onehot_processing(x):
    #sample only
    return [0,0,0,1,0]

df['a'] = df['a'].apply(lambda x : x + onehot_processing(x))
print (df)
                                   a
row0  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
row1  [2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
```

Solution with [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
df['b'] = df.apply(lambda x : x['a'] + onehot_processing(x['a']), axis=1)
print (df)
                    a                               b
row0  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
row1  [2, 3, 4, 5, 3]  [2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
```

You can also change function a bit:

```
def onehot_processing(classID, numberOFclasses):
    one_hot_vector=np.zeros(numberOFclasses)
    one_hot_vector[np.array(classID)-1] = 1
    return (one_hot_vector.astype(int).tolist())


df['b'] = df.apply(lambda x : onehot_processing(x['a'], 8), axis=1)
print (df)
                    a                         b
row0  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]  [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
row1  [2, 3, 4, 5, 3]  [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
```

**Engine working code**

```
  Training_Frame['b'] = Training_Frame.apply(lambda x : onehot_processing(int(float(x['Onehot_column'])), numberOFclasses), axis=1)
```

Comment: thanks a lot for you answer,just one how may put this in a loop because the vector values will change based on the given index

Comment: Super, glad can help!

Comment: do you have an idea how can I do it in a loop ?

Comment: I am not sure if understand, because `apply` is for `loop`. Test is with `def onehot_processing(x):
    print (x)
    #return [0,0,0,1,0]`

Comment: the returned vector isn't the same it change depending on the give index and each index is valid only for one row of the dataframe

Comment: thanks a lot for your help. your last update still doesn't solve the loop problem ?

Comment: Unfortunately not, but I am looking for solution.